# Need help getting this auto-download header to show the right path

Tags: php, include, header, path

I have a page with mp3s that are playable from a player, and there are also links to download the songs.  When the user clicks on the download link, it needs to open the download dialog instead of opening a media player, so it was recommended to me to use this header script:

includes/auto-download.php:

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['path'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
readfile($path);
?>
```

And then on my main page, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="includes/auto_download.php?path=Media/Audio/Date/song.mp3">Song Name</a>
```

I seem to be doing something wrong with my paths, as when I click the link, the download box opens, and I can download a file with the correct name, but it doesn't contain any information.

To elaborate on my file structure, I've got this:

/Patrons (where my main index.php page is with my link

/Patrons/includes (where my auto-download.php script is)

/Patrons/Media/Audio/Date/  (this is where all the songs are)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change HTML code to this:

```
 <a href="includes/auto_download.php?path=../Media/Audio/Date/song.mp3">Song Name</a>
```

OR change PHP code to this:

```
 readfile('../'.$path);
```

Comment: I came back to delete this, because I just figured it out too-but you answered in time! :-D  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

$path needs to be the relative path to the file from the web root. with no leading slash. If the files are outside the web root you should use a fullpath (`/home/webuser/song_files/song.mp3`).

For example `$path = 'song_files/'. $_GET['name_of_the_file'];`

You should also check if the file does not exist and exit with an error.
 Here is an example I made in codeigniter.

```
function _begin_download($document_data) {
    basepath = 'uploads/';
    $filepath = basepath . $document_data->filename;
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        header("Content-type: " . $document_data->mimetype);
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($filepath));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $document_data->filename . '"');
        readfile($filepath);
        exit();
    } else {
        exit('File not found.');
    }
}
```